# The signal <n1<1>_IBUF> is incomplete

Tags: vhdl

I am trying to write a VHDL module but I am having some input problems, here is my code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
--use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_signed.all;


entity binary_add is
    port( n1 : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    n2 : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    segments : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    DNout : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0));

end binary_add;

architecture Behavioral of binary_add is
begin

DNout <= "1110";

process(n1, n2)

variable x: integer;


begin

x:= conv_integer(n1(3)&n1(2)&n1(1)&n1(0)) + conv_integer(n2(3)&n2(2)&n2(1)&n2(0));

if(x = "0") then

segments <= "10000001";

elsif(x = "1") then

segments <= "11001111";

else

segments <= "00000000";

end if;

end process;

end Behavioral;
```

I am getting these errors:

```
WARNING:PhysDesignRules:367 - The signal <n1<1>_IBUF> is incomplete. The signal
   does not drive any load pins in the design.
WARNING:PhysDesignRules:367 - The signal <n1<2>_IBUF> is incomplete. The signal
   does not drive any load pins in the design.
WARNING:PhysDesignRules:367 - The signal <n1<3>_IBUF> is incomplete. The signal
   does not drive any load pins in the design.
WARNING:PhysDesignRules:367 - The signal <n2<1>_IBUF> is incomplete. The signal
   does not drive any load pins in the design.
WARNING:PhysDesignRules:367 - The signal <n2<2>_IBUF> is incomplete. The signal
   does not drive any load pins in the design.
WARNING:PhysDesignRules:367 - The signal <n2<3>_IBUF> is incomplete. The signal
   does not drive any load pins in the design.
WARNING:Par:288 - The signal n1<1>_IBUF has no load.  PAR will not attempt to route this signal.
WARNING:Par:288 - The signal n1<2>_IBUF has no load.  PAR will not attempt to route this signal.
WARNING:Par:288 - The signal n1<3>_IBUF has no load.  PAR will not attempt to route this signal.
WARNING:Par:288 - The signal n2<1>_IBUF has no load.  PAR will not attempt to route this signal.
WARNING:Par:288 - The signal n2<2>_IBUF has no load.  PAR will not attempt to route this signal.
WARNING:Par:288 - The signal n2<3>_IBUF has no load.  PAR will not attempt to route this signal.
WARNING:Par:283 - There are 6 loadless signals in this design. This design will cause Bitgen to issue DRC warnings.
```

The errors seems complicated but actually it says, I think, cannot route the other 3 inputs of my n1 and n2 signals. I do not why this is happening but all I want to do is displaying summation of n1 and n2 signed numbers into 7-segment display. If anyone can help me to figure out this issue, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: Don't use `std_logic_arith` or `std_logic_signed` - I've [written about why not](http://www.parallelpoints.com/node/3).
Second: you have created an asynchronous process, which is not great practise in FPGAs which are designed for use (and the tools expect you to use) in a synchronous fashion.  Create a clock input and use it.  You *can* do it asynchronously, but until you *really* know what you're doing, avoid it.  Once you really know what you're doing, chances are you'll avoid it as well, because you understand how nasty it will be :)

I'd make my ports of `signed` type and `use ieee.numeric_stdd.all;`.  Or even use the `integer` type on the input ports.  If this is the top-level block, you'll need to put a wrapper around to take std_logic_vectors on the outermost pins, turn them into integers and feed them into the block you've written above:

```
n1 <= to_integer(signed(n1_pins));
```

Then you need to do something like this...

```
architecture Behavioral of binary_add is
begin
DNout <= "1110";
process(clk)
  variable x: integer;
begin
  x:= n1+n2;
  case x
    when 0 => segments <= "10000001";
    when 1 => segments <= "11001111";
```

etc

Or create a constant array to convert integer to 7-segment and do

```
segments <= int_to_7seg(x);
```