# The signal is incomplete the signal does not drive any load pins in the design

Tags: vhdl, fpga, xilinx

I'm a total newbie in VHDL and I was trying to write something that can increment the values displayed in a seven segment display with the push of a button(a button for each display). It synthesises and generates but with warnings and in the end when I press the buttons on the board nothing happens. here are my warnings:

WARNING:PhysDesignRules:367 - The signal  is incomplete. The signal
   does not drive any load pins in the design.

WARNING:Par:288 - The signal B1_IBUF has no load.  PAR will not attempt to route this signal.

of course there is one for each button
I've looked at these solutions
[The signal <n1<1>_IBUF> is incomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082599/the-signal-n11-ibuf-is-incomplete)
[VHDL - PhysDesignRules:367](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21939298/vhdl-physdesignrules367)

but I couldn't understand them or maybe they are not really relevant

and of course here is my code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity top is
Port (CLKIN : in std_logic;
        B1 : in std_logic; --buttons
        B2 : in std_logic;
        B3 : in std_logic;
        B4 : in std_logic;           
        AN3 : inout std_logic; --if the display is on or not
     AN2 : inout std_logic;
     AN1 : inout std_logic;
     AN0 : inout std_logic;
     LED : out std_logic_vector(6 downto 0)); --the logic vector to be used for each display
end top;

architecture Behavioral of top is
signal CTR : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(8 downto 0); 
signal LED0 : std_logic_vector(6 downto 0); -- since every display will have different                 number I need for vectors
signal LED1 : std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);
signal LED2 : std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);
signal LED3 : std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);
shared variable int1 : integer range 0 to 11 :=0; --counter for each display
shared variable int2 : integer range 0 to 11 := 0;
shared variable int3 : integer range 0 to 11 := 0;
shared variable int4 : integer range 0 to 11 := 0;
begin   

--it does display these things!
LED0 <= "1000000"; -- displaying 0
LED1 <= "1000000";
LED2 <= "1000000";
LED3 <= "1000000";

-- button listener
process(B1,B2,B3,B4)
begin
if(B1='1') then
    int1:=int1+1; --when I press a button it increases the number
    if (int1=10) then -- if it is more than 9 it should reset
        int1:=0;
    end if;
elsif (B2='1') then
    int2:=int2+1;
    if (int2=10) then
        int2:=0;
    end if;
elsif (B3='1') then
    int3:=int3+1;
    if (int3=10) then
        int3:=0;
    end if;
elsif (B4='1') then
    int4:=int4+1;
    if (int4=10) then
        int4:=0;
    end if;
end if;


end process;

   Process (CLKIN)
  begin
  case  int1 is --all of these "case" s are for converting from integer to display vector
when 0=> LED0 <="0000001";  -- '0'
when 1=> LED0 <="1001111";  -- '1'
when 2=> LED0 <="0010010";  -- '2'
when 3=> LED0 <="0000110";  -- '3'
when 4=> LED0 <="1001100";  -- '4' 
when 5=> LED0 <="0100100";  -- '5'
when 6=> LED0 <="0100000";  -- '6'
when 7=> LED0 <="0001111";  -- '7'
when 8=> LED0 <="0000000";  -- '8'
when 9=> LED0 <="0000100";  -- '9'
when others=> LED0 <="1111111"; 
end case;

case  int2 is
when 0=> LED1 <="0000001";  -- '0'
when 1=> LED1 <="1001111";  -- '1'
when 2=> LED1 <="0010010";  -- '2'
when 3=> LED1 <="0000110";  -- '3'
when 4=> LED1 <="1001100";  -- '4' 
when 5=> LED1 <="0100100";  -- '5'
when 6=> LED1 <="0100000";  -- '6'
when 7=> LED1 <="0001111";  -- '7'
when 8=> LED1 <="0000000";  -- '8'
when 9=> LED1 <="0000100";  -- '9'
when others=> LED1 <="1111111"; 
end case;

case  int3 is
when 0=> LED2 <="0000001";  -- '0'
when 1=> LED2 <="1001111";  -- '1'
when 2=> LED2 <="0010010";  -- '2'
when 3=> LED2 <="0000110";  -- '3'
when 4=> LED2 <="1001100";  -- '4' 
when 5=> LED2 <="0100100";  -- '5'
when 6=> LED2 <="0100000";  -- '6'
when 7=> LED2 <="0001111";  -- '7'
when 8=> LED2 <="0000000";  -- '8'
when 9=> LED2 <="0000100";  -- '9'
when others=> LED2 <="1111111"; 
end case;

case int4 is
when 0=> LED3 <="0000001";  -- '0'
when 1=> LED3 <="1001111";  -- '1'
when 2=> LED3 <="0010010";  -- '2'
when 3=> LED3 <="0000110";  -- '3'
when 4=> LED3 <="1001100";  -- '4' 
when 5=> LED3 <="0100100";  -- '5'
when 6=> LED3 <="0100000";  -- '6'
when 7=> LED3 <="0001111";  -- '7'
when 8=> LED3 <="0000000";  -- '8'
when 9=> LED3 <="0000100";  -- '9'
when others=> LED3 <="1111111"; 
end case;
--this is the clock counter, this part works fine, I've tried it before
if CLKIN'event and CLKIN = '1' then
  if (CTR="000000000") then
    if (AN0='0') then 
      AN0 <= '1';    
      LED <= LED0;                -- the letter n
      AN1 <= '0';
    elsif (AN1='0') then 
      AN1 <= '1';        
      LED <= LED1;             -- the letter n
      AN2 <= '0';
    elsif (AN2='0') then 
      AN2 <= '1';    
      LED <= LED2;             -- the letter A
      AN3 <= '0';
    elsif (AN3='0') then 
      AN3 <= '1';
      LED <= LED3;             -- the letter E
      AN0 <= '0';
    end if;
  end if;
  CTR<=CTR+"000000001";
  if (CTR > "100000000") then   -- counter reaches 2^13
    CTR<="000000000";
  end if;
end if;
  End Process;
End Behavioral;
```

I know there that it is not very concise but I'll try to get better:)

and here is my .ucf

```
NET "LED<0>" LOC = "L14";
NET "LED<1>" LOC = "H12";
NET "LED<2>" LOC = "N14";
NET "LED<3>" LOC = "N11";
NET "LED<4>" LOC = "P12";
NET "LED<5>" LOC = "L13";
NET "LED<6>" LOC = "M12";
NET "AN0" LOC ="F12";
NET "AN1" LOC ="J12";
NET "AN2" LOC ="M13";
NET "AN3" LOC ="K14";
NET "CLKIN" LOC ="B8";
NET "B1" LOC ="A7";
NET "B2" LOC ="M4";
NET "B3" LOC ="C11";
NET "B4" LOC ="G12";
```

thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure about the initial state here.

The way I see it, none of `AN0` to `AN3` test equal to `'0'` from the initial state. As a consequence, none of the blocks updating `LED` and `AN0` to `AN3` are executed, so the carefully prepared LED state is unused, so all of these connections are optimized out, back to the inputs that now have no effect on the outputs.

At this stage, the compiler wonders why you have declared an input that doesn't affect anything in the design.

Comment: I thought when you don't initiate a signal or variable, it automatically puts the 0 or null. Plus it displays the 0000, it's just that I can't change it

Comment: No, and it's even worse than that: initializers are only respected in simulation -- for synthesis, you need an explicit reset mechanism.